# POST method does not display but GET method does

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

My `POST` method does not display on the webpage, but my `GET` method does even though I haven't create a method with it in my global.js. Does the `GET` method come with `POST`? I want my `POST` to display not `GET`. How do I do that? I know that my `POST` work i think because in network (that is in the browser with console), the `POST` method is there, and the preview prints out the `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`. How do I make `POST` to display on the page instead of `GET`.

***Button.php***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">                </script>
    <script src ="global.js"></script>
    <title>Button POST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <button id ="postbutton" onclick="location.href='storage.php'">GO</button><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

***storage.php***

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['json'])){
  $_SESSION['object'] = $_POST["json"]; 
  print_r($_SESSION);
  echo 'True';
}else {
  echo 'False';
}
```

***global.js***

```
var oject = [{name:'John', age:17},{name:'James', age:22}];
var json = JSON.stringify(oject);


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#postbutton').click(function(){
    $('#output').html('sending..');
      var jobject = JSON.stringify(oject);
      console.log(jobject);
      $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'storage.php',
        data:{json:oject},
      })
      .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: well you are setting the window.location.... You can not make an Ajax call and set the location at the same time. Why are you redirecting?

Comment: @epascarello that was just an example, what i am doing is redirecting it to other page that is not `storage.php`. Thought it would make no difference but seems like it did.

Comment: Well you would need to redirect after the Ajax call is done. So put it in the done method.

Comment: @epascarello tried it before and it didn't work. Displayed `Array() False`

Answer (score 1):

Your GET method is work because you used onclick with `location.href` method .That will always redirected with GET method so it can display your output ! But to work with `POST method in ajax` you need to remove onclick method and append return data to body element .

**Button.php**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">                </script>
    <script src ="global.js"></script>
    <title>Button POST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <button id ="postbutton">GO</button><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

**global.js**

```
var oject = [{name:'John', age:17},{name:'James', age:22}];
var json = JSON.stringify(oject);


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#postbutton').click(function(){
    $('#output').html('sending..');
      var jobject = JSON.stringify(oject);
      console.log(jobject);
      $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'storage.php',
        data:{json:oject},
      })
      .done(function(data){
       $("body").append(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D it seems like it works now, but how do I redirect it to other page and still have the value? What I am doing is storing the value into `storage.php` and using that value into another page.

Answer (score 0):

Why there's a `onclick` in button which you happen you call `$.ajax()` at the same time:

`<button id ="postbutton" onclick="location.href='storage.php'">GO</button><br>`

If you want to use `$.ajax()` no need for `onclick`. You can call `location.href` indside `done(function(data) {})` if it met your conditions and you want to redirect the user somewhere else.